# What is the difference when using IPlatformInitializer In Prism

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I've recently started to learn how to use Prism on Xamarin Forms, and I was seeing both Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio.

I created a project in Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio and noticed that in the Visual Studio Template Pack the same `UnityApp` Project differ with the Xamarin Studio version. In Visual Studio the `App` class constructor has a parameter of type `IPlatformInitializer` while the Xamarin Studio version does not.

I will like to know what is the difference between them and when to use each one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xamarin Studio Templates have not been updated because my Mac went down :)

You only need to use the IPlatformInitilizer if you want to register platform specific services.  It's not required.

Comment: So I can make a PR on github to update the template version on Xamarin Studio?

Comment: That would be perfect :)